# Best way to assign property to javascript property

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vueJs computed to create options for my component like this:

```
computed:{
  fileOptions() {
    let fileOptions = [
      {
        event:'event',
        name:'Abcd',
        disabled://based upon some condition,
        display://based upon some condition
      },
      {
        event://based upon some condition,
        name:'Open Presentation',
        disabled://based upon some condition,
        display://based upon some condition
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

The event, disabled and display property are based upon multiple conditions.

One way of doing this is by using ternary operator

```
disabled:this.state.libraryActive=='presentations'?false:true
```

However, it is easy for one condition but for multiple conditions it becomes difficult.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use another computed property:

```
computed:{
  fileOptions() {
    let fileOptions = [
      {
        event:'event',
        name:'Abcd',
        disabled: this.isAbcdDisabled, // based upon some condition,
        display: this.isAbcdVisible // based upon some condition,
      },
      {
        event: this.getEventName, // based upon some condition,
        name:'Open Presentation',
        disabled: this.getDisabled(this.getEventName), // based upon some condition,
        display: this.getVisible(this.getEventName) //based upon some condition
      },
    ]
  },
  isAbcdDisabled ()
  {
    return this.state.libraryActive === 'presentations' && !this.admin ? false : true
  },
  isAbcdVisible ()
  {
    return true;
  },
  getEventName ()
  {
    return this.canEdit ? 'edit' : 'add';
  }
},
methods:
{
  getDisabled (eventName)
  {
    switch(eventName)
    {
      case 'edit': return false;
      case 'add': return true;
      default: return false;
    }
  },
  getVisible (eventName)
  {
    switch(eventName)
    {
      case 'edit': return true;
      case 'add': return true;
      default: return false;
    }
  },  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ternary operator, you could make it much easier:

`disabled: this.state.libraryActive !== 'presentations'`

It will return `false` if `this.state.libraryActive` is equal to `'presentations'` and `true` otherwise.